I'm using @typescript-eslint/parser to parse a typescript function, how can I get the range of the function?
I am trying to write a script that reads a TypeScript file, and returns the function names from that
function getFunctionsFromFile(filePath) {
    const code = readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    const parsed = parse(code, { loc: true }); 
    const functions = [];
    parsed.body.forEach(node => {
        if (node.type === 'FunctionDeclaration') {
            functions.push(node.id.name);
        }
    });
    return functions;
}

It is reading the file addNumbers.ts -
export const addNumbers = (num1: number, num2: number) => {
  return num1 + num2
}

and the value code is
'export const addNumbers = (num1: number, num2: number) => {\r\n' +
    '  return num1 + num2\r\n' +
    '}\r\n'

When this is parsed with parse I get his error
const bodyStart = this.block.body?.range[0] ?? -1;
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

When logging out this.block.body there is no range property, so I think it is parsing the function incorrectly. Is there a way to define the function format for this?
I have tried using typescripts 'createSourceFile' to read from but this didn't work as I had hoped, I've had a look at the documentation for @typescript-eslint/parser but the props I could pass to parse but couldn't find one that could work.
I have added an .eslintrc.js file to the project but that didn't seem to help either (this is in a seperate folder to the TS project I am trying to read from)

️ typescript-eslint contributor here.
I've played around with this locally and it looks like it works if you parse with range: true (i.e. const parsed = parse(code, { range: true });). I'm not personally very familiar with the parser, but this seems like simply a bug in the parser to me, triggered in the snippet by references to function parameters. Consider filing a bug report on GitHub.
Cheers!
